# Eclipse Mars not finding classes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've a maven's multimodule project in Eclipse and I'm having a compilation problem when importing some classes. I first thought it was some problem with the Maven configuration because the not found classes are from the test package but then I found that other classes importing the same test class from the same module also fails. In code, my project looks like this:

```
library
|-model
|-resource
|-int-test
|-... some other modules that doesn't matter
```

The first classes I found with problems were this:

```
// this class belongs to the test package (src/test/java) from the model module
// In my Eclipse project it's red underlined with the error message:
// The import com.library.app.commontests.author.AuthorForTestsRepository cannot be resolved
import static com.library.app.commontests.author.AuthorForTestsRepository.*;
...

// This class belongs to the int-test module (test package also)
public class AuthorResourceIntTest {...}
```

Same case for this class

```
import static com.library.app.commontests.author.AuthorForTestsRepository.*;
...

// This class belongs to the resource module (test package)
public class AuthorResourceUTest {...}
```

Maven is configured to package the test classes so I can set it as a dependency in the other modules, this is the configuration:

#### model/pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>model</artifactId>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- versionId setted in app/pom.xml in the pluginManagement section -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

#### resource/pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>resource</artifactId>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.library</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
        <!-- versionId setted in dependencyManagement section -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.library</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As I said, my first thought was to think in a bad configuration in my pom, but then I found the same error in a class from the same `model` package, this is the class:

```
import static com.library.app.commontests.author.AuthorForTestsRepository.*;
...

// This class belongs to the same model module (also from test package) 
// as AuthorForTestsRepository
public class AuthorRepositoryUTest {...}
```

In every case I have the same error in Eclipse. The `AuthorForTestsRepository` class exists (I swear) and I have the same error for other classes of my system (there are other `*ForTestRepository` with the corresponding `*RepositoryUTest`, `*ResourceUTest` and `*ResourceIntTest`).

It's a bug in Eclipse? Where should I look for the solution. Thanks in advance for your answers.

## Update #1

I tried 2 things from the command line to test if it's something with Eclipse or with Maven:

#### First

I ran `mvn test -PintegrationTests-wildfly` from the `int-test` module. `integrationTests-wildfly` is a profile to run the integration test in a Wildfly container (by default I skip the integration test because they take too long). The container starts without errors and when trying to run the test I have the following error message:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 32.114 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.library.app.author.resource.AuthorResourceIntTest
com.library.app.author.resource.AuthorResourceIntTest  Time elapsed: 32.112 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive com.library.app.author.resource.AuthorResourceIntTest.createDeployment()
     at com.library.app.author.resource.AuthorResourceIntTest.createDeployment(AuthorResourceIntTest.java:43)
```

But I don't know what does it have to do with the class not found from the test package.

#### Second

Then I ran `mvn clean install -PintegrationTests-wildfly` from the main project (`app`). The `model` and `resource` modules test and compile correctly. In the `int-test` module the container starts correctly but I have a problem creating a table in the test database.

What I don't understand is that some tests where already working and I didn't change anything from the code they're supposed to test!

#### Conclusion

There're some code completions that aren't working in Eclipse, and that's the main problem I'm facing in this post, so I don't want to go into details of my projects that doesn't have anything to do with this problems.

Thanks again in advance for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the project or running maven from the command line to see if the project runs?

Comment: @efekctive, please refer to the **Update #1** section. Thanks for your time

Comment: If I am reading the exception correctly, the container could not find the class. But do you need to stick to mars?

Comment: Not necessarily, It's just the IDE I'm using for a course. I didn't tried (yet) to run the tests in Netbeans. Again, the problem is with some `imports` that should be OK and I don't know what to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I moved my code to another workspace and that solved my problem. Not completely but creating the project from scratch and moving just the files (`.java`, `.xml` and so on). In 2 or 3 moments I had to update some modules with `right click -> Maven -> Update Project`. I realized of that option thanks to the *Markers* View (*Window -> Show View*).

Don't know if it has something to do but my previous project was in my Dropbox folder, maybe it has some conflict with Maven, but I'm not sure about this.

Thanks for all the comments and views to my question.